# Symfony2 Application Architecture - how to make a function available in all controllers?

Tags: symfony, architecture, doctrine-orm

I'm building an application where users are tied to accounts (as in, multiple users all share an account), then other entities - lets call them products are tied to the accounts. The products are associated with the accounts and only users that are tied to that account can edit the products.

The difference being in my case, there are many different entities being shared in the same model.

If it was just the one (product) entity, it wouldn't be a problem to have a method in my ProductRepository like:

```
public function checkOwnership($id, $account)
{
    $count = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('count(s.id)')
        ->where('s.account = :acc')
        ->andWhere('s.id = :id')
        ->setParameters(array('id' => $id, 'acc' => $account))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    if($count == 0)
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('ye..');

    return;
}
```

To make sure the id of the product is tied to the user's account.

The account argument is passed to this function by using:

```
$this->getUser();
```

In the controller.

What is the best way for me to make this function available to the other entities to prevent code duplication? There are (currently) only 3 other entities, so it wouldn't be the end of the world to just have it in each repository, but **I'm just wondering if there were a way to create a 'common' or global repository that follows good standards?** I'd sure like to know about it.

**Edit:**

Or have I just completely over-thought this? Can I just create a 'Common' directory in my 'MainBundle', define a namespace and add a use statement at the start of my controllers that need access to the function?

Comment: It might just be me, but I've read through this carefully and I'm still not sure what you're actually asking. Are you trying to share a function between controllers or Repository classes? It would probably help to show some more relevant code.

Comment: It's probably confusing - my fault. In short, I was trying to ask if there is a way to share a common function amongst repository classes. Since asking this I've just duplicated the function in question across my three repository classes, since there will be only three for the time-being and there are some minor differences so...

Comment: It would help if you could show the function you're sharing. If you need common functionality between repositories, you might want to look into [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: @RobMasters - The function I was attempting to share was in my question, apologies that the question was so ambiguous. I've marked Gremo's answer as correct since I think code duplication did make the most sense in my situation after all (and the second solution sounds like it would have worked if I needed it to). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I fully understand your question.

**Solution one, duplication, easy**: let [`@ParamConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) do the job (automatic response to `404` if doesn't exist)

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/pets/{id}")
 */
public function showAction(Pet $pet)
{
    // Current logged user
    $currentUser = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    // Owner
    $ownerUser = $pet->getUser();

    if(!$currentUser->equals($ownerUser)) {
        // 401, 403 o 404 depends on you
    }
}
```

**Solution two, DRY, a bit harder**: use [JMSAOPBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) and define an interceptor that intercepts all request to you controller and actions (show, delete, etc.). The pointcut (connected to the interceptor) will get the current user from the context and the owner from the entity. Then you do the check...